# What do you do with error "Unexpected end when reading token. Path 'state Machine.<>t__builder'"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asynchronous

I'm posting this up as it may help someone else. And I didn't find any similar answers on web search.

If you get this `Unexpected end when reading token. Path 'state Machine.<>t__builder'`

It usually because of a method you called lacks the task/async/wait modifiers in your function call. Your code will compile and run quite happily. No errors, warning or messages.

I found it by calling a web service method from another web app and desktop app.  That method returns to me a JsonResult, unfortunately, the web function call fails silently or doesn't complete as its an asynchronous call and you have called in synchronously.

Vs2019, Asp.Net.Core 3

Answer (score 0):

Whats I did was this

```
public JsonResult Foo(string sfoo)
{
    return _service.FooMethod(foo) //returns a JsonResult
}
```

What I should have done was this

```
public async Task<JsonResult> Foo(string sfoo)
{
    return await _service.FooMethod(foo) //returns a JsonResult
}
```